# link_to rails helper to an external link is throwing an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Here is my link:

```
<strong>Shortened Url:</strong> <%= link_to link.short_url, "http://www.google.com/search?q=balut+egg&espv=2&biw=1280&bih=678&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=CngVVanlMIG5ogSap4GQDQ&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ#imgdii=_&imgrc=qnYT21R-r5VDRM%253A%3BIbuD8fXhkqTEDM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.bizarrefood.com%252Fblog%252Fwp-content%252Fuploads%252F2012%252F08%252Fbalut.jpg%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.bizarrefood.com%252Fblog%252Ffertilized-duck-embryo-balut%252F%3B295%3B300", class: "short-link" %>
```

The error I get is this:

```
ActionController::RoutingError:  
       No route matches [GET] "/search"
```

Why is it trying to look for an internal route? How do I fix this?

Comment: Is your link.short_url valid?

Comment: Add the output of `rake routes`

Comment: Can you make sure this is working? `link_to "Visit Other Site", "http://www.rubyonrails.org/"`

Comment: That works for me Sharvy

Comment: Is it something to do with the query paramters?